# How to delete a single record in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller

Using Laravel 5 I m trying to delete a single record within a controller, here is my code:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
     $employee = Employee::find($id);
     $employee->delete();
     return Redirect::route('noorsi.employee.index');
}
```

My view page code is:

```
<td><a href="employee/{{$employee->id}}/destroy" class="btn btn-default">Delete</a></td>
```

My route is:

```
Route::delete(employee.'/{id}', array('as' => 'noorsi.employee.destroy','uses' => Employeecontroller.'@destroy'));
```

That did not work.

How do I fix the implementation ?

Comment: Does it give any errors?

Comment: It redirects to the page: http://serviceweb:8000/employee/07716a5ed38e4e168e2178a9de201fb7/destroy and stats that 'Whoops, page not found.'

Comment: What is your `routes` line? I'd bet the 'destroy' part should be before the 'id' part

Comment: Route::delete($key.'/{id}', array('as' => 'noorsi.'.$key.'.destroy','uses' => $controller.'@destroy'));

Comment: Change the Route method to `Route::get()` since now you're doing a GET method by opening the link, but you tell Laravel to expect a DELETE method to actually call the controller's method. You're not even calling the function, currently.

Comment: You are calling the destroy method of your controller per GET request, please update your question with the route file. You probably have to call the method with a delete request, or it'll just return a 404

Answer (score 62):

From the official Laravel 5 documentation:

**Delete an existing Model**

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->delete();
```

**Deleting An Existing Model By Key**

```
User::destroy(1);
User::destroy([1, 2, 3]);
User::destroy(1, 2, 3);
```

In every cases, the number between brackets represents the object ID, but you may also run a **delete query on a set of models**:

```
$affectedRows = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->delete();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Comment: +1, Also read: [How To Delete Record By ID using Laravel Eloquent](https://devnote.in/how-to-delete-record-by-id-using-laravel-eloquent/)

Answer (score 12):

So the Laravel's way of deleting using the `destroy` function is

```
<form action="{{ url('employee' , $employee->id ) }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <button>Delete Employee</button>
</form>
```

You can find an example here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart-intermediate#adding-the-delete-button
And your route should look something like this

```
Route::delete('employee/{id}', array('as' => 'employee.destroy','uses' => 'Employeecontroller@destroy'));
```

It works with eg:`Route::resource('employee', 'EmployeeController');` and it should also work with how you set up your destroy route.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you have a bad routing problem. You're trying to use a 'get' verb to reach a route defined with a 'delete' verb.

If you want to use an anchor to delete a record, you should add this route:

```
Route::get('/employee/{id}/destroy', ['uses' => 'EmployeeController@destroy']);
```

or keep using a delete verb, but then you need to use a form (not an anchor) with a parameter called `_method` and value `'delete'` stating that you're using a 'delete' verb.

Comment: Even though this would work, it would be better to change the view code, to send a delete method. This is the default behavior in Laravel and is well documented, so that coming back to his code, would make it easy to understand what he's doing. So the author should probably go with your second suggestion

Comment: @ricktap Yes. Like 90% of the times, there is a "fast" solution, and a "right" solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Route::get('/showcon/{del_id}/delete','MainController@deletemsg');
  public function deletemsg($del_id){

  $mail=Mail::find($del_id);

  $mail->delete($mail->id);

  return redirect()->back(); 
  }

  <a href="showcon/{{$m->id}}/delete">del</a>
```