# jQuery not working or displaying any errors in console on Laravel 6

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I recently upgraded my project from Laravel 5.8 to 6, now jQuery seems to be broken, I have tried using CDNS as well as Laravel mix but jQuery just doesn't seem to work. It's not even displaying any errors in console even if I create syntax errors purposely...This has also caused my datatables to stop working, is there something am doing wrong? what's the best way to use jQuery in Laravel

Layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>NeptuneWare</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700"/>
   
    <!--Select2-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.css" />

     <!--Custom Font-->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/font/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/customstyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="{{ asset('dist/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.0/css/brands.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"/>
    
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#f8f9fa">
      <div id="app">
        <!-- Main Header -->
        @include('layouts.header')
        @yield('content')
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        <!-- Footer -->
        @include('layouts.footer')
        <!-- ./wrapper -->
      </div>
    <!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->
    <!--Stock Scripts-->
    <script src="{{asset('dist/js/vendor/jquery.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    
    <!--Select2-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.full.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('.select2').select2()
    </script>

    <!--Datatables-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

One of files using jQuery:

```
@extends('home.base')
@section('action-content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="container" id="cart-window">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="cart-header">
                <h3>Billing & Shipping Details <span class="cart-return pull-right"><a href="{{url('/cart')}}"><i class="ionicons ion-ios-cart"></i> Back to Cart</a></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                @if(Cart::Count()==0)
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12" id="empty-cart">
                                    <p>Your cart is currently empty</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Return to Shop</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                @else
                <div class="card detail" id="delivery-card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card top-small-card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <h5><strong>Existing Addresses</strong></h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <select class="select2 form-control" id="newAddress">
                                            <option selected disabled>Please Select Delivery Address</option>
                                            <option value="0"><a href="" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newAddressModal">Add New Address</a></option>
                                            @foreach($shippingaddress as $address)
                                            <option value="{{$address->id}}">{{$address->house_number}} {{$address->street_name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="address" readonly rows="10"></textarea>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                @if(Cart::Count()>0)
                <div class="card detail">
                    <div class="card-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text" id="cart-summary">
                            Order Summary
                        </p>
                        <hr/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                {{Cart::Count()}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                @if(Cart::Count()==1)
                                Item
                                @else
                                Items
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <p>
                                    Subtotal
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    VAT (15%)
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Total to Pay
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6" id="cart-totals">
                                <p>
                                    R{{Cart::subtotal()}}
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    R{{Cart::tax()}}
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    R{{Cart::total()}}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
                         <hr/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 continue-btn">
                                <a href="{{url('')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{--  <hr>
                        <div class="row" id="delivery-method">
                            <select class="form-control select2" id="delivery_method" name="del">
                                <option value="0" selected disabled>Select Delivery Method</option>
                                @foreach ($delivery_method as $item)
                                <option value="{{$item['delivery_method']}}">{{$item['delivery_method']}} R{{$item['price']}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>  --}}
                    </div>
                    {{--  <div class="card-footer" id="cart-footer">
                        <div class="delivery_type">
                            <a href="{{route('checkout.shipping')}}" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkout-btn" style="color:white"><strong>Checkout</strong></a>
                        </div>
                        {{--  <div class="delivery_type2">
                            <a href="{{route('checkout.shipping')}}" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkout-2" style="color:white"><strong>Checkout 2</strong></a>
                        </div>  --}}

                    {{--  </div>  --}}
                </div>
                <div class="card order-review">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text" id="cart-summary">
                            Order Review
                        </p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <p><strong>Delivery Method</strong> <span class="change-del pull-right"><a href="{{url('checkout/deliverymethod')}}">Change</a></span></p>
                                <p>Delivery</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                @endif

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- NewAddressModal -->
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade show" id="newAddressModal" style="display: none;" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Default Modal</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>One fine body…</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>

@push('custom_scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#newAddress").on("change", function () {   
        renderYourText();
    }
    function renderYourText(){
        var x = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML =x;
    }

    $("#newAddress").on("change", function () {        
    $modal = $('#newAddressModal');
    if($(this).val() === '0'){
        $modal.modal('show');
    }
    });
});

</script>
@endpush
@endsection
```

Console with no errors:

[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijoFm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long hours trying to get the solution to this problem I managed to solve the problem by following [bhavinjr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9294616/bhavinjr) answer to this question [Laravel custom javascript on blade is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963663/laravel-custom-javascript-on-blade-is-not-working/55963744)